# Angular app deployed on Azure successfully, but permission denied message while accessing it

Tags: angular, azure, kudu

**Issue**
I am trying to deploy an Angular app ( Angular version - 8.2.14) on Azure.
I have used to Kudu to deploy the application and the code is deployed from my Github Repo. The deployment status is 'success'.

**Error while accessing the URL of the deployed web application**
"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

**Approaches tried to fix the issue** 
To get more details on the error, I tried enabling the *'Detailed Error Messages' in the App Service Logs* section. But I am not able to get much info from it either. The only info which I find in the 'Detailed Error Messages' is "*This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error*. "

I also checked the *Event logs* and I find the below info,

```
Exception: System.IO.IOException

Message: The handle is invalid.


StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__ConsoleStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)



at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.Write(String value)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProgressWriter.IdleWriter(Object state) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\ProgressWriter.cs:line 109
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback(Int32 id)</Data></EventData></Event><Event><System><Provider Name="HttpPlatformHandler"/><EventID>2000</EventID><Level>4</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>Keywords</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-05-01T16:57:34Z"/><EventRecordID>385268109</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>RD501AC5040133</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>APPLICATION_MANAGER::~APPLICATION_MANAGER | this=05B6D878 [TID 6180] [PID 5664]</Data></EventData></Event><Event><System><Provider Name=".NET Runtime"/><EventID>1026</EventID><Level>1</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>Keywords</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-05-01T16:57:35Z"/><EventRecordID>385269218</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>RD501AC5040133</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
```

I am trying to try other options ( mostly checking for tutorials on deploying Angular apps on Azure) but haven't been lucky to fix this issue yet. 
[image: Directory tree]
    **web.config**

```
    <!-- indicates that the index.js file is a node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <!-- adds index.js to the default document list to allow 
    URLs that only specify the application root location, 
    e.g. http://mysite.antarescloud.com/ -->

    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <add value="index.js" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Post your project directory tree and the `web.config` from App Service. Most probably the web.config doesn't know how to get to your index.html. If you want to avoid all this unnecessary IIS dance, deploy to a Linux worker instead (App Service has both).

Comment: @evilSnobu I have added directory tree and the web.config. Meanwhile, I will take a look into the Linux Worker based deployment as well.

Comment: You published the source project rather than your `dist` content (the webpacked stuff). Your source made App Service generate a Node.js specific web.config, so you need to wipe clean the Web App and redeploy only the static files inside `dist`.  You should have `index.html, main.js, any_other.js` under `d:\home\site\wwwroot` after you redeploy.

Comment: Your input helped me fix  this issue. Under the configuration section -- Path mappings , I changed the physical path to the virtual application to 'site\wwwroot\dist'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message you've gotten, it seems that the application files were not deployed into the expected location.

Please refer to my article (in French) here: http://espacenuagic.com/2019/03/10/deployer-une-application-angular-sur-azure-app-service/
Pay a special attention to the content you're deploying, as shown in this picture:

[image: deploying angular content]

in this example, I'm deploying the content of the 'angled' folder, not the 'dist' folder.

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. Under the configuration section - Path Mappings, I had to change the value of physical path to the 'site\wwwroot\dist'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case I forgot to press "RUN" button in overview menu.